# DELETE request is completing before GET request when trying to findRecord and destroyRecord in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code in ember 2.6; ember-data 2.6.1

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    activate() {
        var route = this;
        var sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
        if (sessionId) {
            localStorage.removeItem('sessionId');
            this.store.findRecord('session', sessionId).then(function found(session) {
                session.destroyRecord();
                route.transitionTo('index');
            });
        } else {
            this.transitionTo('sessions.new');
        }
    }
});
```

I have a logout button that has hbs template code as:

```
<li>{{#link-to 'sessions.delete'}}{{fa-icon "fa-lock"}} Logout{{/link-to}}</li>
```

The `Route.extend` code is executed when /sessions/delete is called!

What I observe is the order of REST calls are:

```
1) ***DELETE*** http://dozee.me:3000/api/sessions/<sessionId>
2) ***GET*** http://dozee.me:3000/api/sessions/<sessionId>
```

The second REST request throws and error because by that time the session/cookie is already cleaned up.

What I expect is the order of the REST calls should actually be reverse but I am unable to figure out why is it not like that!

Any pointers & hints will be appreciated ;)

Comment: Where does this come from then(function found(session)?

Comment: `findRecord` should return a Promise. Isn't it?

Comment: yes but I never saw that function call...that is why i was asking...what I do is this....then( (session)=> {...}); if you use ES6 and fat arrow...so function found is extra in your example ..it can be like this as well then( function(session) { }....try without that...but not sure if naming a function would make a difference...

Comment: This should work! Do you maybe call `findRecord` somewhere else as well?

Comment: That's all of the code I have for the route. I don't see `findRecord` being called anywhere else.

Comment: What happens if you comment this line session.destroyRecord();? Does your index route loads session?

Comment: Yes! If I comment that line, the session object is loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be because ember already have that session on the store and returning that object to you and trying to update the object later via making a GET call.

which can happen after delete because promise was already resolved with store object.

What u can do is look for session object in store first with peekRecord and make findRecord call only if object in not found in store.

Other way would be make a forsed server call for findRecord for session which wont get resolved untill object is returned from server.

Hope this helps you.